# Swift struct array into Dictionary throw a nil value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a `struct` that I need to convert it into a Dictionary

```swift
struct ModelFeedbackServices: Codable {
    let servicesId: String?
    let servicesName: String?
    let category: String?
}
```

And I have an array of the same type `ModelFeedbackServices`

`private var selectedItems = [ModelFeedbackServices]()`

and I need to convert this array into a Dictionary to add it in my parameters here:

```swift
var parameters: [String: Any]? {
    var params: [String: Any] = [:]
    switch self {
    case .submit(let services, let comments):
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       params["FEEDBACK_SERVICES"] = services.asDictionary // Here it comes as nil!
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       params["COMMENTS"] = comments
       return params
   }
}
```

I have created `extension Encodable` :

```swift
extension Encodable {

    var asDictionary: [String: Any]? {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
    }
}
```

The problem is every time I get a `nil` value in `services.asDictionary` inside the `switch` statement

I need the dictionary looks like this

```
{
    "FEEDBACK_SERVICES": [
        {
            "SERVICE_ID": "8",
            "SERVICE_NAME": "ABC",
            "CATEGORY": "1"
        },
        {
            "SERVICE_ID": "4",
            "SERVICE_NAME": "ABC",
            "CATEGORY": "2"
        }
    ],
    "COMMENTS": "any comment"
}
```

Any idea would be helpful

Comment: Your `FEEDBACK_SERVICES` is an array not dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce this `Encodable` extension to get `Dictionary` or `Array` of `Dictionary`

```
typealias JSON = [String:  Any]

extension Encodable {

    /// Converting object to postable JSON
    func toDictionary(_ encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()) -> JSON {
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(self) else { return [:] }
        guard let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) else { return [:] }
        guard let json = object as? JSON else { return [:] }
        return json
    }

    /// Converting object to postable array of JSON
    func toDictionaryArray(_ encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()) -> [JSON] {
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(self) else { return [[:]] }
        guard let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) else { return [[:]] }
        guard let jsonArray = object as? [JSON] else { return [[:]] }
        return jsonArray
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var parameters: [String: Any]? {
    var params: [String: Any] = [:]
    switch self {
    case .submit(let services, let comments):
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       params["FEEDBACK_SERVICES"] = services.toDictionaryArray() // Here it comes as nil!
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       params["COMMENTS"] = comments
       return params
   }
}
```